Restricting specific Github actions on Revert pull requests
This could be very novice question, but I am pretty much new to github actions.
During deployment, we find quite a few problem causing PRs, that we revert by creating Revert PR manually.
But the problem is the mandatory GHAs which takes 3-4 hrs to run even on Revert PRs, halting the deployment.
Options that I considered

Labeling a PR with revert label, but devs can abuse it by manually adding a label to skip GHA checks
Adding Revert in title, and checking , but again if any normal PR contains Revert in their title, will be skipping the checks too.

Is there any way to restrict Github actions running on Revert PRs, without giving hack to developers to skip GHAs on regular PR.
